# Linux: Is it safe to have 100+ mounts to folders?

Tags: linux, ftp, mount, chroot

I am setting up a chrooted environment for users who request SFTP access, essentially their login directory must be /home/xxxx which is not accessible by public FTP,

Would mounting each /home/xxx directory to /srv/ftp/~xxx, possible for a hundred users in the near future be a bad idea for a server environment? Could it slow anything down?

An example:

```
mount --bind /srv/ftp/john /home/john/
```

If you could provide any experience or insight on if I am doing this wrong, feel free to lecture me - I would be very greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an option if you wish to do so, although it'll be a bit hard to maintain.

Another option which is not so bad is to use limited shells for this SFTP users, this way you'll save the pain and have the same results, check lshell since I think it'll cover exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I will consider when I need to, for now I figure just appending new mount commands to a file, and putting it into rc.local on reboot. It only requires a few edits and a single script to admin most of it.